# How to change "Choose an action" to "Complete action using" on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, nfc

I have an an NFC app which allow user to scan their NFC tags and perform some action. I faced an issue which is when user scanned the tag, it will how `"Choose an action"` but not `"Complete  action using"`. The different between these two is, `"Complete action using"` allow user to pick `"always"` button. If it show "`Choose an action"`, it cant remember user decision and user have to choose the app every time they scanned a NFC Tag.

Please checkout below screenshot, picture tell thousand words. How can I force `"Complete  action using"` dialog?

[image: choose an action]
[image: complete action using]

Comment: could you show your code when you construct `Intent` to send it to action chooser?

Answer (score -1):

As it turns out, you cannot alter the Android default `Intent` chooser. All you can do is create your own `DialogFragment` with a list of `Activities` that can respond to a given `Intent` and add buttons with a custom logic. Hope this helps.